# Find and fill intersection of line chart with plot line in highcharts

Tags: angular, highcharts

I am developing application using angular and very new to this high charts. I have requirement where we should get intersection of plot-line and 1st line chart here is the existing code below. Could you please help me to achieve this. I want fill the complete intersection area with color as i highlighted with red color in attachment. Thanks in advance.

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {

    title: {
        text: 'Solar Employment Growth by Sector, 2010-2016'
    },

    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: thesolarfoundation.com'
    },

    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Number of Employees'
        },
        plotLines: [{
            color: '#FF0000',
            width: 2,
            value: 76500
        }]
    },

    xAxis: {
        accessibility: {
            rangeDescription: 'Range: 2010 to 2017'
        }
    },

    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'middle'
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            label: {
                connectorAllowed: false
            },
            pointStart: 2010
        }
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Installation',
        data: [143934, 52503, 57177, 69658, 97031, 119931, 137133, 154175]
    },
{
        name: 'Installation2',
        data: [14393, 2503, 7177, 9658, 7031, 19931, 13133, 14175]
    }]  

});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/series-label.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>

<figure class="highcharts-figure">
    <div id="container"></div>
    <p class="highcharts-description">
        Basic line chart showing trends in a dataset. This chart includes the
        <code>series-label</code> module, which adds a label to each line for
        enhanced readability.
    </p>
</figure>
```

.  [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the reversed `area` series and zones, for example:

```
    series: [{
            ...,
            type: 'area',
            fillColor: 'transparent',
            threshold: 200000,
            zones: [{
                value: 76500,
                fillColor: 'orange',
                color: 'red'
            }]
        },
        ...
    ]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Lom6kcnv/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.area.zones

Comment: Hi Ppotaczek,
Thanks for the quick solution. your solution worked for me but i have other scenario where it is not working as expected.. If you check this one http://jsfiddle.net/manoj_rejinthala1510/Lpyazs5u/11/  its highlighting intersection area along with other area. Do you know how to restrict only to intersection area?

Comment: Hi @Manoj Rejinthala, You can try to use arearange series, example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/v7qb5gxw/